# NavigableMap - Compare based on values

Tags: java, dictionary, compare, comparator

I am trying to implement a NavigableMap with a custom comparator that does a compare based on values rather than keys. I am very very knew to java and coding in general so if my terminology is inccorect or code horrible please forgive me! I have tried finding similar questions to try and replicate the solutions but am still recieving the following errors when I try to compile:

```
java: no suitable constructor found for TreeMap(OrderLineSegments)
    constructor java.util.TreeMap.TreeMap(java.util.Comparator<? super java.lang.Float>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; OrderLineSegments cannot be converted to java.util.Comparator<? super java.lang.Float>)
    constructor java.util.TreeMap.TreeMap(java.util.Map<? extends java.lang.Float,? extends java.lang.Float[]>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; OrderLineSegments cannot be converted to java.util.Map<? extends java.lang.Float,? extends java.lang.Float[]>)
    constructor java.util.TreeMap.TreeMap(java.util.SortedMap<java.lang.Float,? extends java.lang.Float[]>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; OrderLineSegments cannot be converted to java.util.SortedMap<java.lang.Float,? extends java.lang.Float[]>)
```

I am trying to implement the following where Float[] is an array of 4 Floats [x1,y1,x2,y2] representing a line segment.

```
NavigableMap<Float, Float[]> segmentBST = new TreeMap<Float, Float[]>( new OrderLineSegments() );

class OrderLineSegments implements Comparator<Map.Entry<Float, Float[]>> {
public int compare(Map.Entry<Float, Float[]> a, Map.Entry<Float, Float[]> b) {
    float ypos;
    if (a.getValue()[1] < a.getValue()[1]) {
        ypos = a.getValue()[1];
    } else {
        ypos = b.getValue()[1];
    }
    float ratioA = (a.getValue()[1] - ypos) / (ypos - a.getValue()[3]);
    float ratioB = (b.getValue()[1] - ypos) / (ypos - b.getValue()[3]);
    float posA = Math.abs(a.getValue()[0] - a.getValue()[2]) * ratioA + a.getValue()[0];
    float posB = Math.abs(b.getValue()[0] - b.getValue()[2]) * ratioB + b.getValue()[0];
    if (posA < posB) return 1;
    if (posA > posB) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not even sure if this is the best way to do this or if this is even possible so any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `Comparator` is used to compare the *keys*, so `OrderLineSegments` needs to implement `Comparator<Float>`. Hence the error when you're trying to compare `Map.Entry`.

Comment: The error seems normal as the doc says : `constructor of TreeMap<K,V> requires Comparator<? super K>` and you provide a `Comparator<Entry<K,V>>` it cannot be like, can't you inverse key and value ? If you don't have identical values, you may change

Comment: You're breaking NavigableMap's contract. Why not just use a sorted List in this case?

Comment: @Kayaman I'm still learning how to interpret the java documentation - this seems obvious now!

Comment: @daniu I thought a NavigableMap was the best solution as it comes with higherEntry and lowerEntry (this also runs in O(ln(n)))

Answer (score 0):

You could create the comparator as a separate object with a support map and then in the compare method get the values from this same map. After this you can apply your logic to the values ...
You would also need to use an extension of the tree map with an overridden "put" method which puts the content into the support map, before putting it into the actual navigable map.

Something along these lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Sun, 27 Jul 2014 10:19:10 +0100

    class OrderLineSegments implements Comparator<Float> {

        private Map<Float, Float[]> supportMap = new HashMap<>();

        public int compare(Float aKey, Float bKey) {
            Float[] aValue = supportMap.get(aKey);
            Float[] bValue = supportMap.get(bKey);
            float ypos;
            if (aValue[1] < bValue[1]) {
                ypos = aValue[1];
            } else {
                ypos = bValue[1];
            }
            float ratioA = (aValue[1] - ypos) / (ypos - aValue[3]);
            float ratioB = (bValue[1] - ypos) / (ypos - bValue[3]);
            float posA = Math.abs(aValue[0] - aValue[2]) * ratioA + aValue[0];
            float posB = Math.abs(bValue[0] - bValue[2]) * ratioB + bValue[0];
            if (posA < posB) return 1;
            if (posA > posB) return -1;
            return 0;
        }

    }

    OrderLineSegments orderLineSegments = new OrderLineSegments();

    class ExtendendNavigableMap extends TreeMap<Float, Float[]> {

        private OrderLineSegments orderLineSegments;

        public ExtendendNavigableMap(OrderLineSegments comparator) {
            super(comparator);
            orderLineSegments = comparator;
        }

        @Override
        public Float[] put(Float key, Float[] value) {
            orderLineSegments.supportMap.put(key, value);
            return super.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    NavigableMap<Float, Float[]> segmentBST = new ExtendendNavigableMap(orderLineSegments);

    // Start adding elements
    segmentBST.put(1.0F, new Float[]{0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f});
    segmentBST.put(1.9F, new Float[]{0.3f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f});
    segmentBST.put(1.1F, new Float[]{-0.3f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.4f});

    segmentBST.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s:%s%n", k, Arrays.toString(v)));
}
```

Output:

```
1.9:[0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
1.0:[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
1.1:[-0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
```

While this solution is convoluted and ugly, it should definitely work. It is more natural to use a tree set with an object containing both the key and value and then create a custom comparator for it with the implementation logic which was suggested in your question.

Comment: thank you! This is now compiling.

Although the ordering of the map doesn't seem to be obeying the compare function.

For instance:

If the map already contains: 1.3283 : [1.3283, 89.719, 5.7766, 70.22] 

and I add: 3.2011 : [3.2011, 72.564, 14.316, 55.937]

It should insert to the left (i.e. a lower position) and look like:

{3.2011 : [3.2011, 72.564, 14.316, 55.937], 1.3283 : [1.3283, 89.719, 5.7766, 70.22]}

but it is added to the right (upper position) like this:

{1.3283 : [1.3283, 89.719, 5.7766, 70.22], 3.2011 : [3.2011, 72.564, 14.316, 55.937]}

Comment: It appears the compare isn't being called. I placed a println statement inside the compare block and nothing was printed. I assume this indicates that its not being used and the natural Key ordering is being used? Is there something else I need to do to implement this?

Comment: My apologies, this is indeed the case. I have updated the answer. Can you please try the code again? Please let me know, if it worked for you.

Comment: the compare function is now called however I've encountered the following error whilst using lowerEntry and higherEntry:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at OrderLineSegments.compare(planesweep.java:31)
Inside compare.
 at OrderLineSegments.compare(planesweep.java:22)
Inside compare.
 at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1295)
 at java.util.TreeMap.getLowerEntry(TreeMap.java:494)
 at java.util.TreeMap.lowerEntry(TreeMap.java:700)
 at planesweep.main(planesweep.java:241)

Comment: I'm now invested to see how I can make this work but agree that this is getting a little out of hand! I've been looking at NavigableSet and can probably get away with just storing the Float[] information, I may try that as an alternative if resolving this NavigableMap issue is too difficult.

Comment: If you copy and paste and run the code in this answer you will not get a nullpointer exception. Possibly you are using a map that is not initialized in the comparator. I have removed some lines of code that were not necessary.